# How's JavaScript's native sort function implemented?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Let's see an example first.

```
var everything = [4,'Red', '$200', 'white', 7.4, 12, true, 0.3, false];
console.log(everything.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;})); 
// [4, "Red", "$200", "white", false, 0.3, true, 7.4, 12]
```

I think this is weird, even when I know `Number("Red")`, `Number("$200")` and `Number("white")` all give `NaN` when comparing.

Why is `4` at the first of the result? I guess it has something to do with the implementation of `Array.prototype.sort`, so how can I see its implementation?

Comment: It's usually native code, so I imagine it would vary for each implementation. Probably should check the spec.

Comment: FWIW, ES5 says the compare function specified [produces implementation-defined behavior](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.11) because it is not a "consistent comparison function".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Specification

According to [ECMAScript 5 - Section 15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11),

> If *comparefn* is not **undefined** and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is **implementation-defined**.
>
> [...]
>
> A function comparefn is a consistent comparison function for a set of values S if all of the requirements below are met for all values a, b, and c (possibly the same value) in the set S [...]
>
> - Calling comparefn(a,b) always returns the same value v when given a specific pair of values a and b as its two arguments. Furthermore, Type(v) is Number, **and v is not NaN**. [...]

That is to say, if the return value of the comparison function is NaN, then the behaviour of the call to sort is 'implementation defined'.

---

## In practice

Google Chrome and NodeJS (V8 Engine), as well as Opera (Futhark/Carakan) return:

```
[4, "Red", "$200", "white", false, 0.3, true, 7.4, 12]
```

Firefox (SpiderMonkey) returns:

```
[false, 0.3, true, 4, "Red", "$200", "white", 7.4, 12]
```

Internet Explorer returns:

```
["Red", "$200", false, 0.3, true, 4, "white", 7.4, 12]
```